# Connect Django app with Elasticsearch using Haystak

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am creating a Django app that has millions of data in it. So, for better result I am trying to use Elasticsearch to store the data. I am also trying to use Haystack for search process. But currently I am stuck in the process of connecting the Django app with Elasticsearch through Haystack.

My database configuration is:

```
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_elasticsearch',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '9200',
        'SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS': False,
    },
```

In the settings.py file I have haystack and elasticsearch app installed.
Also I have copied Haystack setting as per the documentation in settings.py.

```
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch2_backend.Elasticsearch2SearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

The elasticsearch runs perfectly

```
{
  "name" : "TN1nVS-",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_manishojha",
  "cluster_uuid" : "zZQxFpkCT8qUO_GVVQAmHA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.1",
    "build_hash" : "19c13d0",
    "build_date" : "2017-07-18T20:44:24.823Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Now all that is required is the connection between the application and elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Haystack [does not support](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html#elasticsearch) yet Elasticsearch v5.5.1.
You have to rollback to Elasticsearch v2.4.1 and also to add the package elasticsearch2-haystack via pip (or any package manager) in order to port the Elasticsearch v2x engine to haystack. After that the settings will be

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'elasticsearch2_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
},
```

}

I hope it will help you.